What is the second property of the connection one-form?
According to this lecture @min 43:58, the connection one-form $\omega$ in a principal bundle has the properties:

$\omega_p(X^A_p)=A$

$\left((\lhd g)^{*}\omega\right)_p(X_p)=\left(\mathop{Ad}_{(g^{-1})}\right)_{*}\omega_p(X_p)$


Which I think is saying on the LHS that the pullback of the right action by a $g \in G$ on a vector at point $p$ is on the RHS the push forward of the adjoint (a vector in the Lie algebra) acting on the result of the one-form after this one form has already acted on a vector field, i.e. $\omega_p(X_p)$, yielding Lie algebra elements. So do we have two vectors in the Lie algebra interacting on the RHS, $\left(\mathop{Ad}_{(g^{-1})}\right)_{*}$ and $\omega_p(X_p)$? Should the parentheses be differently placed? Or, more likely, am I completely misunderstanding what's going on?

Here is what is correct: $$((\vartriangleleft g)^*\omega)_p(X_p)=Ad_{g^{-1}}(\omega_p(X_p)).$$ On the left hand-side, you have a one form $((\vartriangleleft g)^*\omega)$ which is the pullback of $\omega$ under the right action of $g$. You evaluate this form at $p$ and feed it with $X_p$. On the right hand-side you have a Lie algebra element $\omega_p(X_p)$ to which you apply the transformation $Ad_{g^{-1}}$.

Fantastic. Am I pushing the envelope by asking why the minus in $Ad_{g^{-1}}$?

... meaning that $Ad_{g^{-1}}$ is no longer applied to just $\omega_p,$ but $\omega_p(X_p),$ which should be a vector, not a covector.

The group $G$ acts on differential forms via the pull-back. This action is a right action. Hence, you would like to also consider a right action for the right hand-side of the equation. Otherwise the equation would only hold for the 0 one-form. The action defined by $Ad_g$ is a left action while the one defined by $Ad_{g^{-1}}$ is a right one.

Is $p$ always supposed to be in the base manifold?

No, $p$ is a point of the principal bundle. Also $\omega$ is a one-form on the principal bundle with value in the Lie algebra of $G$. This is why it makes sense to talk about $\omega_p$.

This is mind boggling! So "reality" (space-time in GR) is the base manifold. Ultimately it is about moving along points in the manifold. However, we have to use one frame or another, which are points $p$ in the fiber / Lie group. At the identity we have the Lie algebra with a one-form that because there is a Lie algebra isomorphism at every point, we can also use elsewhere along the Lie group to "jump" to the next fiber from chosen frame to chosen frame.
